# Number is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created my migration with limit 8 in the chat_id column:

```
class CreateChat < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :bots do |t|
      t.integer :user_chat_id, null: false, limit: 8, unique: true
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The migration is created perfectly and I can insert data into it.
But if I do:

```
class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'user_chat_id'
end
```

The following error occurs, 5187762395178250 is out of range for ActiveModel :: Type :: Integer with limit 4.

I researched and looked in the documentation, but I did not find anything about it.

Comment: Can you tell more about how you're getting the error? What is it that you're doing that's throwing that error? Can you post the relevant trace as well?

Comment: @vee For example, when I acess: http://localhost:3000/chat/5187762395178250 This error is displayed, But if the number is small the error does not occur. I think it's an ActiveModel validation.

Comment: Looks like you need to suppress the creation of the primary key in the database, which by default is the id. So, rollback the migration and modify the migration file to include this line:

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to suppress the creation of the primary key, which by default is the id. So, rollback the migration and modify the migration file to include this line first:

```
create_table :bots, id: false do |t|
  t.integer :user_chat_id, null: false, limit: 8, unique: true
  ...
  t.timestamps
end ...
```

The options you applied to user_chat_id will make it the primary key.

Comment: Check this out for more information:  http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

We also deal with this error, here is our case:

1. Change DB type from int to bigint (MySQL table, column `id`)
2. When `id` column exceeded maximum int value (2.1 billion - unsigned integer), our app returned this error in some API

Restart `puma` server resolved it.
Just this simple command, it took us around 4 hours. :((

If you are using `Unicorn` or `Passenger 5` or any others for your web server, try to **restart** it, I think it can resolve your issue.

Hope this helpful, thank you.